# how to pass a `Class<T>` of `List<MyDevice>`?

Tags: java, json, string, list, generics

I wrote this method:

```
   public <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> klazz)  {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T object = null;
        try {

            object = mapper.readValue(json, klazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }
```

I want to call it:

```
List<Device> devicesList= jsonUtils.jsonToObject(response.getEntityInputStream(), new TypeLiteral<List<Device>.class);
```

what is the correct way to pass a `Class<T>` of `List<Device>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to call it with a `TypeLiteral` (and that's indeed the way to capture the generic type of the list), your method needs to accept a `TypeLiteral<T>` as argument, not a `Class<T>`.

And the caller needs to use an anonymous class to properly capture the type:

```
jsonUtils.jsonToObject(response.getEntityInputStream(), 
                       new TypeLiteral<List<Device>>() {});
```

Comment: What is mapper? Is it an instance of Jackson ObjectMapper? If so don't use TypeLiteral, but Jackson's TypeReference, which serves the same purpose and works the same way. http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28byte[],%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference%29